# Using Array vs. String in Gulpfile

Tags: node.js, gulp

Wondering why when I look at some people's gulp files do they sometimes put a string in an array vs. just plain string.

for example

```
  mochaTest: {
        options: {
            reporter: 'spec'
        },
        src: ['test/**/*-spec.js']
    },
```

Why is 'spec' a string but src is an array with a string?  There's only one string for src, but people are using [] around it to make it an array, why?

Answer (score 0):

**src** is an array because it allows multiple and single values that can be used either as single/multiple wildcard patterns, single/multiple individual files, or a combination of both.

For example:

```
mochaTest: {
    options: {
       reporter: 'spec'
    },
    src: ['test/**/1-spec.js', 'test1/**/2-spec.js', 'experiment/3-spec.js']
},
```

In this example, **reporter** is not an option that allows multiple values so it's not an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think most people do this to allow themselves to add another glob pattern in the future in case they need it.

Personally I do this often, to not have to bother adding or not array brackets in my patterns since I know they're already there